# Mongoose Function Cannot be Called in different file in Node.Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created some functions containing MongoDB methods in one File. It works well when I access the function from the same file, but when I am trying to access the function from another file, it doesn't work.

Here is the code

```
const Chain = require('../database/models/chains')

const getlatestChain = async () => {
    try {
        const thechains = await Chain.countDocuments()
        if (thechains < 2) {
            throw new Error('there is only one chain!')
        }
        return thechains
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}


module.exports = {
    getlatestChain: getlatestChain
}
```

It doesn't work when I call it from another file

```
const thechain = require('../src/utils/chain')
require('../src/database/database')

thechain.getlatestChain()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('how many documents : ' + result)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

error

```
TypeError: Chain.countDocuments is not a function
```

Comment: You need to provide code of `'../database/models/chains'` to let everyone know how your code looks like in that file,  as it error outs here `await Chain.countDocuments()`..

Comment: Hi @srinivasy , yes it works when I add const Chain =  require('../src/database/models/chains') .. another question, can you explain why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

check the chains model to make sure you are exporting the countDocuments function, check the spelling as well if it is exported